# Plugin developer automated documentation

Tags: plugins, filters, actions, documentation

I have published a plugin which provides a nice extensibility. Now, I want to provide my users an **automated** PHP Documentation which describes the API Functions, **Filters and Actions** like this page here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/deleted_blog/ so they can create their own Add-On for the plugin.

Now, for example here is a custom action:

```
<?php
/**
 * Fires immediately after the toolbar.
 * 
 * @since 3.2
 */
 do_action("RML/Sidebar/Content", $folders);
```

and I want to generate (CLI) the PHP documenation for this. I have found PHPDoc for this but it does not support actions / filters nor events. What does WordPress.org use for this, is there any open source for this? I hope i have explained all in a nice way!